# ASP .NET Core 6 - .razor components - Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I come from a background in ASP.NET MVC 5 on .NET 4.8.

I've been trying to wrap my head around the new razor pages, and can't seem to get routing to work, or understand it, even.

I don't want to use the `@page` directive, because I want more flexibility over how things are routed. (I've also found it doesn't even work as I expect it to from the documentation, so yay for an entirely new stack that's vastly different from the old one)

Let's say for instance we use the default ASP.NET Core 6 application and replace `Index.cshtml` with `Index.razor`. So far I've found this to be an effort in futility. I also think this is the wrong way to go about it, or I'm missing something intrinsic to how `.razor` files and routing are intended to work.

I *could* create a `.cshtml` that immediately renders the `.razor` file, but that seems like it's missing the point.

I've added this to my Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

All I really want is the ability to have the functionality in composable razor components.

I like the move toward dependency injection due to its separation of concerns; however it also makes it quite difficult to find the exact module you're looking to plug into the service stack.

Eventually I want to use a `MapDynamicControllerRoute` due to the tenancy needs I have in the project. This is why I need more than just a `@page` directive.

It's frustrating being shot back to the state of `I don't know what I don't know` and be unable to ask google the right questions. Right now I'm stuck at `it no work`.

Comment: The `@page` directives are usually used with the default `<Router>` component. Did you consider writing your own router? I guess you could tailor it exactly to your needs.

Comment: This is one of those cases where I don't know what I don't know. How's this router work?

Comment: I never built one myself, but [this github repo](https://github.com/chrissainty/BuildingACustomRouterForBlazor) contains an example.